# Sending Google Forms responses to specified e-mail address on Submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I am trying to setup Google Form in a way that once Form Submiter hits "Submit" button the responses are not only populated in dedicated spreadsheet but also sent via e-mail to particular mailing group

Probably the best way would be to use Google Scripts and Triggers, including "onsubmit", "Mailapp.sendmail" functions but my struggles here are:
a) to get the responses directly from just submitted form
b) to change "send from" e-mail address (that would send an e-mail to mailing group) to submiter's e-mail
c) connect the form responses with mailapp.sendmail function

I have tried something like this but it holds the issues mentioned above:

```
function OnSubmit(e) {  var formResponses = 
FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
Logger.log(formResponses.length);
var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
Logger.log('Last response to the question "%s" was "%s"',
           itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
           itemResponse.getResponse());
MailApp.sendEmail ("email@mydoiman.com", "Form Submited " + Date.now(), 
FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses());
}}
```

I really appreciate all your help! Because I am total amateur in this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) to get answer in an email you can do that :

```
function sendAnswers(e) {
  var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var emailRespondent = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
  var html = "";
    for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    html += "<b>"+item.getItem().getTitle()+"</b> : "+ item.getResponse() + "<br>";

  }
  MailApp.sendEmail("EMAIL_RECIPIENT", "Form answers", "", {htmlBody:html})
}
```

b) it is not possible to change the 'To' of email.

c) Yes we use the MailApp function.

=> do not forget to create a trigger to have the function run on onFormSubmit.

=> in emailRespondent you have email of person that submit the form if you click to collect email of respondent. if you don't do that comment the line i.e.

```
  // var emailRespondent = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
```

Stéphane

Comment: This is perfect Stéphane, works charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just one more thing. Re: point b) So the system / script limitations are: you just cannot change "send from" e-mail address? In a way: abc@xyz.com submits the form and sends the e-mail from: abc@xyz.com to dec@surveys.com?

Comment: Script run with user credential so the from when you send email is email of your account. You can't use another user email as it is you who send the email and you are not allowed to use any email you want, sounds logic.

Comment: Don't forget to learn answer as good answer it will help others users of they have the same issue.